# Ajax beginform not working in JQuery in PartialView MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

From the main controller view we load the partial view like this:
    
           @Html.Partial("MapPartial", Model)

Inside the Partial View I want to render a map. Currently I have a Ajax beginform with submit button which calls the controller action and onSuccess loads the data in the JavaScript function which renders the map as below. This works fine.

```
<div id="map"></div>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetData", "Directory", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "mapInit" }))
{
    <button class="btn" type="submit">update map</button>
}
```

Update: Okay I understand the JQuery code/function is loaded first when the controller main view is loaded but how can I automate the map to be rendered when the partial view is selected. I do not mind using a loading/progress bar which might delay of a second to render the map. please help.

Comment: why are u hiding and showing same div $(".ContentReplacable").hide();
     $("#MapPartial").show();. is that ajax called action hitting?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this google maps trigger.

google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

where "map" is your google maps object

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.post('Directory/GetData',{},function(data){            
        mapInit(data);
    },"json");
function mapInit(data) {
$('#MapParial').html(data);
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what u trying to do but just try this post function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post('Directory/GetData',{},function(data){            
            mapInit(data);
        },"json");
    function mapInit(data) {
    $('#MapParial').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Dinesh I am trying to render the map when the partial view is loaded. I tried the above code the data is coming fine but the map is not rendering. The above code is run when the controller is loaded. but I need it to run when the partial view is loaded.

Comment: Where u need to run the partial view

Comment: I Edit The Code Just Try It

Comment: If you see the first few lines of code in the question above there is a button which shows the map div and hides the other divs. in the map div is where I want the map tobe rendered just after the button is clicked.

Comment: Does not work, maybe it will not work in partial view, need a seperate view for the map